# How to create a common interface to be adjusted by different functions in Python and Tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, factory

I am writing a Python/Tkinter code to calculate many different petroleum engineering thermodynamic (PVT) properties and parameters. I have set up sequential interfaces to channel the problem to specific types of properties, e.g. oil density. The user starts from a broad classification of correlations (oil, gas, and water) until he gets to a specific correlation, e.g. oil FVF, Standing´s correlation.

As there are a large number of correlations for each PVT parameter (oil density, oil FVF, etc.), I would like to have a common interface that specific correlations would call for basic data input (temperature, pressure, etc.). Minor adjustments to the common interface would be required by specific correlations as they differ slightly in the required input data.

My question is, What is the best way to handle this problem?

Apparently, factory design is a possible solution, but I am not quite sure of this. I know nothing about this subject and before I delve deep into it, I would like some reassurance that this is the way to go.

Below I show part of my code where I use traditional classes and functions to create an interface for one specific correlation. As can be seen, the interface creation is part of correlation function itself, which will become cumbersome when new correlations are added.

## 1.2 OIL FVF (Bo)

class OilFVF():
    """ This class provides the actual workings of the oil 
    FVF correlations."""

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    master.title('OIL FVF CORRELATIONS')

# 1.2.2 Standing (1947) 
def Standing(self):
    # calculations function
    def standing_1947_fvf(rs):
        # get input parameters
        p = float(p_enter.get())
        temp = float(temp_enter.get())
        api = float(api_enter.get())
        gammag = float(gammag_enter.get())
        # go on to calculations
        yg = 0.0009*temp - 0.0125*api
        den = 18*(10**yg)
        gor = gammag*((p/den)**1.204)
        gor = ("%8.0f" % gor).strip()
        print("Rs = ",gor)
        # clear current muod entry
        rs.delete(0, END)
        # insert result into entry widget
        rs.insert(0, gor)

    # create new window
    standing = Tk()
    # correlation title label
    title_label = Label(standing,
                        text="Standing (1947)", 
                        fg = "light green", 
                        bg = "dark green",
                        font=('arial', 14, 'bold'))
    title_label.grid(row=0, columnspan=3) 

    # correlation functional expression
    expression_label = Label(standing,
                             text="Rs = f(p,T,API,gammag)")
    expression_label.grid(row=1, columnspan=3)

    # pressure input                                                    
    Label(standing, text="p =").grid(row=2,column=0)
    p = DoubleVar() # default value = 0.0
    p_enter = Entry(standing,
                width=10,
                textvariable=p)
    p_enter.grid(row=2,column=1)
    Label(standing, text="psi").grid(row=2, column=2)
    # temperature input                                                    
    Label(standing, text="T =").grid(row=3,column=0)
    temp = DoubleVar() # default value = 0.0
    temp_enter = Entry(standing,
                width=10,
                textvariable=temp)
    temp_enter.grid(row=3,column=1)
    Label(standing, text="F").grid(row=3, column=2)
    # API input                                                    
    Label(standing, text="API =").grid(row=4,column=0)
    api = DoubleVar() # default value = 0.0
    api_enter = Entry(standing,
                  width=10,
                  textvariable=api)
    api_enter.grid(row=4,column=1)
    Label(standing, text="-").grid(row=4, column=2)
    # gas specific gravity input
    Label(standing, text="gammag =").grid(row=5)
    gammag = DoubleVar()
    gammag_enter = Entry(standing,
                   width=10, 
                   textvariable=gammag)
    gammag_enter.grid(row=5,column=1)
    Label(standing, text="-").grid(row=5, column=2)
    # Result block
    Label(standing, text="Rs =").grid(row=7)
    rs = Entry(standing,width=10)
    rs.grid(row=7,column=1)
    Label(standing, text="scf/STB").grid(row=7, column=2)
    # Calculate button
    standing_button = Button(standing,
                             text="Calculate",
                             command=(lambda : standing_1947_fvf(rs)))
    standing_button.grid(row=6,column=1)
```

## -------------------------------------------------------------

The code is working the way it is, but my concern is how to extend it to many different correlations. A common interface would make this task a lot easier and the code would be much shorter.

I thank you all in advance for any guidance you can provide me with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: This question might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean, but what I am asking for is basic guidance to solve the problem of how to extend my program to many different correlations. I have added part of the code just to illustrate what I explained in words. I believe it is not crucial for anyone to go through my code to answer my question.

Comment: ***"not quite sure what you mean"***: You state: ***"The code is working the way it is"*** therefore [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is better suited to get a answer.